# why there is more than 60Gb incoming traffics on my eth0?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, traffic

when i run

> nload -m

, i find there is more than 60Gb incoming traffics on my eth0 , but no outgoing.

i want to know is it a bug of nload or other possible reason ? thanks!

Comment: You've made this question incredibly easy to answer by giving us lots of detailed information about your system and what it's doing </sarcasm>

Comment: Take a look at [nethogs](http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `tcpdump -n -i eth0` to see what's coming in. 
if it is a long running host on a busy ethernet segment, just broadcasts could accumulate up to such size ...